What would the natural diet of Bigfoot be?
Assume for a moment that Bigfoot/Sasquatch was a real animal living in the temperate rainforests and to a lesser degree other areas of the Pacific Northwest. Something like the depiction in Max Brooks' Devolution but without the catastrophic backdrop provoking unusual behavior, a 6-7 foot tall bipedal great ape, maybe more omnivorous than a gorilla/orangutan but less so than a chimp or human given their temperate habitat.
What would the natural diet of such an animal be? Making comparisons with IRL great apes is difficult because most primates are restricted to tropical zones where their preferred foods (esp. fruit and nuts) are most abundant, and humans get around this largely by either big game hunting or growing our own food and storing it for winter (which is a bit too anthropomorphic for a giant great ape). I can easily see salmon runs being an important part of their annual diet, given how important they are for other large NW Pacific omnivores (bears and humans). Are there any plants that local Native American groups found useful to gather or cultivate that could be also be staple foods for large non-human primates (acorns)?

For those of us who have never heard of Devolution before, what are the characteristics other than height?  Posture, gait, build, paw/hand/foot configuration for both fore and rear limbs?  Form follows function - there's a reason that humans walk and run long distances upright and mountain gorillas don't, and it's mostly related to evolutionary diet.

Max Brook's Sasquatches' eyes are at least 7-8 feet from the ground.

@Ash wonderfully unspecific about how they got up there ;) Sasquatches clearly are a giant flat foot shaped body that can easily conceal itself in grass and small bushes that traverses by bouncing with 7-8 foot retractable eye stalks to watch for predators and nosey cryptozoologists with cameras, a hitherto unreported species of mollusk that feeds on vegetable detritus on the forest floor, a bouncing slug.

@Pelinore Well if they're a mollusk they must be related to the true unicorn. (Not sure if you'll get the reference there, read Equoid but only if you're into Lovecraftian stuff.)

Since what we suspect of 'Bigfoot/Sasquatch' is basically that he might be a kind of great ape, why would his diet not - barring geographic variations - be broadly similar to those of all the other great apes, except us?
Wouldn't any other great ape have diet broadly similar to however one might average out the cuisine of chimpanzees, gorillas, orangutans, and bonobos but not us.
If modern man steps aside in favour of troglodytes or Neanderthals, isn't that about right?

Their diet is almost entirely chupacabra-based. This predation has reduced the chupacabra population so much that chupacabras are really hard to find these days. Which in turn caused the bigfoot population to decline.


maybe more omnivorous than a gorilla/orangutan but less so than a chimp or human given their temperate habitat.

This seems unlikely. I would have your sasquatches living like bears, able to eat almost anything and liable to grab any small animal it can catch for a snack. Everything from insects to eggs would be food for this creature.

I like this answer. Also, the long periods of hibernation could explain why they are seldom seen.

+1. One of the areas that sees common Bigfoot reports, the Ouchita Mountains in Oklahoma and Arkansas, supports a population of black bears in the hundreds. Adult male black bears can be small, but they can also weigh up to 500 lbs. So their diet certainly supports mammals of that mass in that area.

Oh, noticing the Cascadia area was specifically called out. Of course that area actually contains Grizzly Bears, which are much much heavier than black bears.

The short answer is, their diet would be EVERYTHING.
At the size and bulk we are talking about, there is very little chance they would be able to survive on plants alone this far north.
As a longer answer, lets count some options:

Leaves. The vast majority of leaves are edible, including to humans. They are just not particularly nutritious. A Sasquatch would have a much better sense of smell, and significantly more robust digestive tract, so I can totally see them just grazing on maple leaves etc until full. Maple, ash, birch, beech, alder and hazel, even elm, all have edible leaves, and even the few that are harder on digestion (like oak leaves) might not be a challenge to this creature, just tangier flavor.
Bark. The cambium, or underbark of most trees is edible to humans/humanoids, and was a staple of starvation-food flour replacement for most northern humans. The prodigious strength and powerful flat teeth of the squatch means they can get to it easier.
Nuts. most nuts and hard seeds are at least somewhat edible, including acorns. The one issue with acorns is the high tannin content, but it can be washed out of crushed acorns by just dunking them into a river for a few days: something that might be within Squatch mental capabilities to do.
Weeds. Plenty of weeds and grasses are perfectly edible to a human, just not particularly nutritious since we can barely digest them. However, if your Sasquatches can (even partially) digest cellulose, they will have a another dietary staple in just grazing like a buffalo.
Flowers. Surprisingly, nearly all flowers (save for the most poisonous plants) are perfectly edible, and easy to digest. The pollen inside is very calorie-dense
Conifer needles. Young needles are edible for humans raw. The only problem is their mechanical hardness which could damage human digestive system. But I would assume Bigfoot's enormous jaws and teeth can easily grind needles to edible paste. Young pine cones, and pine seeds from older cones are edible as well, as long as one can masticate them properly.
Lichen. Fungi were already covered by someone else, but lichen is so much more important, because it is almost impervious to weather, grows even very far north, and is not seasonal. Horsehair lichen (wila, hoopoop) is a staple of Native American diet for this reason. Plus, its kinda funny to imagine a brown, hairy Bigfoot munching on brown, hairy lichen.
Carrion. hunting is cool and all, but primitive humanoids excelled at finding carrion, or stealing meat from predators. A troop of  1000 pound, 7 feet tall Sasquatches is probably too slow to chase down a deer, but would be perfectly capable of tracking down a wolfpack that killed said deer, and shooing them away from the kill.
Corral hunting. Sasquatches are almost certainly too big, heavy and energy-hungry to be persistence hunters like humans. But if they were intelligent enough, I can see them using corral hunting to chase a whole herd of reindeer into a chokepoint (like a cliff wall, or a narrow pass), and then slaughter them manually. Just grab the deer one by one and snap necks, no weapons necessary.
Seals. North America still has some seal habitats, and beached seals are pretty easy to kill for a sapient hominid  with sledgehammer hands. Anything a kodiak or a polar bear can do, a Sasquatch can do as well, possibly better. Better still, if we consider the "Aquatic Ape" theory, and imagine Sasquatches as good swimmers or even divers.
"Seafood". lets set aside active fishing for a second. The Northern Pacific and Atlantic alike, not to mention the Great Lakes, can provide them with plenty of food if they just prowled the beaches and put anything organic in their mouths. There would be thousands of tons of washed out kelp, carcasses of dead whales, seabirds and their eggs, shellfish, clams, crabs, crays, snails and worms of all kinds. Dead, rotting fish might sound nasty to a human (except Icelanders who love their rotten shark meat), but completely palatable to a Sasquatch.
Hibernating animals. I think we can safely assume Sasquatches do not hibernate, it would require too many changes from the hominid baseline. So what can they do throughout winter? Of course, use their near-human intelligence and sharp senses to track down and dig out the animals that do hibernate, and are not expecting a rude wake-up. All those helpless sleeping rodents, reptiles and amphibians would not even know they are being dug out and eaten. A bear might put up a brief fight, but not very effective when surprise dogpiled by 10 hungry Sasquatches.
the Soft Meat. You know what kind of an animal is pretty much helpless against a Sasquatch, and would likely not even see it coming until too late? YOU. Up until guns were introduced to North America, the only reliable defense humans could put against a troop of Sasquatches would be either to outnumber them 10x1, or move the whole tribe 1000 miles South, just to be on the safe side (and promptly run against the Southern Skunk Ape - which is just as nasty as a Sasquatch, possibly worse, since it comes from the Everglades.)


I think Sasquatch would mostly avoid humans: not much meat, and they put up a heck of a fight for their size.

+1 for the rest of the answer, but spears, slings, bows and arrows have all been used by humans for millennia and would all be a serious problem for a Sasquatch. We also tend to be good at traps. Like other large predators (crocs, tigers, sharks), they might occasionally snatch a child or woman or anyone who got lost in the forest, but they wouldn't be a staple, and taking too many humans is likely to backfire.

My assumption was that a Sasquatch would be an ambush predator, given its near supernatural stealthiness, and thus most human weapons would be kinda useless against one. Also, human tribal warfare shows that just because humans are hard to kill, does not mean other humans would not try, and so would Sasquatches. Humans hunting Squatches back just means the two humanoid species would enter a cycle of revenge, and kill each other more often, not less. The same vengeful reasoning would work both ways, But I wager revenge-killing would be easier for a ninja-gorilla to do.

If a Sasquatch is going to hunt down a large animal, I would expect it to go for deer sooner than seals. Seal may be clumsy on land, but once they get to water it's game over. Deer are more abundant and their habitat overlaps more with that expected for Sasquatch. Some reported sightings include Sasquatch hunting deer, either by running them down or via cooperative ambush. Throwing rocks is also a common trope in sightings, which could double as a hunting method.

Human tribal warfare shows that humans are the only species that's had real success killing humans. If sasquatches have near-human intellect and organization and reasonably large numbers, then sure. Otherwise, I back the humans. In the forest, they'll travel armed and in groups. Outside the forest, the Squatch doesn't have stealth. Consider tigers - at least as dangerous in their own habitat, and man-eaters exist, but humans aren't a primary food source for most of them. The only thing that could set Squatches apart from other predators is organization.

@user111403, I based my assumptions on OP's choice of a Sasquatch type, which was definitely an intelligent, and tribal tool user, closer to Australopithecus than a chimp. Basically, slightly dumber humans, not "mindless" animals.

Taking the description from the book a Sasquatch is 7-8 feet tall and weighs in at up to 1000lbs, maintaining that as an active hunter gather needs, ballpark, ~9000 calories a day. Taking into account only foods that are native to North America, acorns are going to be a must, that's going to require certain gut and kidney adaptations to deal with the tannin load, and/or sophisticated preparation techniques. I would also expect them to utilise roots including rushes and Jerusalem artichokes heavily as well. That's over and above foraging the usual fungi, (and if they eat acorns rare they may be able to eat some that are lethal to humans), fruit, and seeds that are visible to the uninitiated. They'll hunt as well, probably much the way our paleolithic ancestors did, running prey to death over days and seasonal abundances like the salmon run will be important events on their calendar. Primates, generally, suck at hibernation but the Sasquatch may be an exception, if so, and if the Sasquatch moves on a slow round across a wide territory it could explain why the legendary Wendigo is only seen at intervals of many years. The annual round is common in nomadic cultures, there are certain goal destination-times based on particular events like the ripening of certain plant foods, animal migrations, etc... but the route and stops between are fluid. I'm thinking a multi-year version of the same since even a small band consuming that many calories is going to be hard to support long term in a narrow territory.

They are omnivorous, with a diet similar to humans
All great apes share similar nutritional needs.  Nuts, seeds, leaves, fruits, roots, and meat.  Since Bigfoot are almost certainly great apes, and probably even members of the homo genus, their diets are probably very similar to that of human hunter gatherer societies. Like humans, they will probably be able to eat most of the plants that are toxic to other animals that we eat like onions, garlic, and mint, but it also means that any food source that is toxic to humans will likely be at least somewhat toxic to bigfoot.
They are probably also tool users
There are two kinds of bipeds in this world, those with diminutive forelimbs to save on weight and caloric needs, and those with forelimbs that do something other than walking like flying or tool use.  Having large human like arms and being an obligate biped is a big evolutionary disadvantage unless you use your forelimbs for a lot of lifting and carrying.
This means that their tool use should be more advanced than a non-obligate biped like a chimpanzee or bonobo.  However, we never find evidence of complex tools or weapons designed for 9ft tall human like creatures, and we don't see any archaeological evidence of giant homes and farmlands which means that their tools use is likely Paleolithic in nature.  A sharpened rock they use as a knife may be indistinguishable from a Native American axe or adze head if there is no handle attached to reference for the scale of the intended hands.
They are trappers, not hunters
They are too big and have too slow of a frame to be effective hunters without the invention of weapons, but if they made bows, spears, etc. to scale for their own use, then we would have archeological evidence of this.  Instead, they most likely rely on trapping.  Trapping is far more time and energy efficient than hunting.  A skilled trapper can feed a whole family with less than an hour of work a day whereas hunters have to spend all day looking for food.  So if bigfoot are trappers, then it would be a lot easier for them to conserve energy and meet the caloric needs of their larger frames.  Furthermore, the snares, fish baskets, nets, pit traps, etc. left behind by a bigfoot are indistinguishable from similar traps left behind by human trappers because traps are made to the scale of your prey, not to the scale of the trapper.  These also tend to be made of biodegradable materials, so they will not leave a long archeological record the way that stone tipped weapons and tools do.

Bamboo!
You haven't got any bamboo I hear you cry? Well why not? Just add some then.
Gigantopithecus, huge jaws and molars suitable for a hard plant fibre diet, remains found in areas of China .. we've only ever found the jaws and teeth .. obviously? it ate bamboo much like a panda.
I like to imagine it as a squat little four foot or less round bodied biped with a giant head to house those big jaws and teeth (for crunching up all that bamboo) that fooled all the paleontologists into believing it was a giant among apes, on top of a pair of outsized feet.. because why not.

Mushrooms
We have a few good other options but they overlook the sheer diversity of edible mushrooms the northwest offers: chantrelles, morels, oyster mushrooms, chicken of the woods. The list goes on.
Realistically, this area could support a decent population of these large primates on mushrooms alone.
Berries
Blackberries grow so abundantly that they are essentially weeds. Salmonberries, raspberries, blackcurrant, and huckleberries are also going to be common finds.
Supplementing the diet with berries would be extremely important, as "fruit" as we traditionally think of it isn't a big feature of the northwest.
Fish
Salmon on migration are of course the first thing people think of, but if your bigfoot is capable of basic tool use, char and trout are distributed all throughout the area. Bass are also widespread, but are an invasive species spread by humans, so may not fit your use case.
Game
Ultimately, I do not think the large game animals of the northwest would be appropriate for bigfoot to hunt, but opportunistically stealing full or partial catches from other predators likely is. The bears (northwest bears won't get very large, typically) and cougars of the area likely won't want to tangle with your guys. They are the bully here.
